# How can find the find occurence in a window/group and fetch all unbounded rows prior to that?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following Dataframe that contains sessions along with the customer-id and b boolean indicating a purchase.

```
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|accountId|customerId|sessionDate|didPurchase|
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|walgreens|       001| 2021-09-30|      false|
|walgreens|       001| 2021-07-30|       true|
|walgreens|       001| 2021-05-30|       true|
|walgreens|       001| 2021-04-30|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-08-04|       true|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-06|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-05|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-01|      false|
|    tesco|       001| 2021-09-21|      false|
|    tesco|       001| 2021-09-20|      false|
|    tesco|       001| 2021-01-30|      false|
|    tesco|       001| 2021-01-01|      true |
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

For each window of `accountId` and `customerId`, I need to get all rows prior to the oldest purchase (i.e. `didPurchase` should be true) when you group by `accountId` and `customerId` and sort by `sessionDate` descending.

My expected resultset should be so:

```
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|accountId|customerId|sessionDate|didPurchase|
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
|walgreens|       001| 2021-05-30|       true|
|walgreens|       001| 2021-04-30|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-08-04|       true|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-06|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-05|      false|
|walgreens|       002| 2021-07-01|      false|
|    tesco|       001| 2021-01-01|      true |
+---------+----------+-----------+-----------+
```

The snippet below is what I've used in Zeppelin to create the df. I'm familiar with SQL window functions but baffled me.

```
   SELECT accountId
        , customerId
        , sessionDate
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, customerId ORDER BY sessionDate DESC) AS rn
        , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY accountId, customerId) AS visits_per_customer
     FROM myvisits
```

Is this where I need to use `UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`? is so, a small SQL snippet would help. Thank you.

```
import java.sql.Date

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  ("walgreens", "001", Date.valueOf("2021-09-30"),  false),
  ("walgreens", "001", Date.valueOf("2021-07-30"),  true), 
  ("walgreens", "001", Date.valueOf("2021-05-30"),  true), 
  ("walgreens", "001", Date.valueOf("2021-04-30"),  false),
  ("walgreens", "002", Date.valueOf("2021-08-04"),  true),
  ("walgreens", "002", Date.valueOf("2021-07-06"),  false), 
  ("walgreens", "002", Date.valueOf("2021-07-05"),  false), 
  ("walgreens", "002", Date.valueOf("2021-07-01"),  false),
  ("tesco",     "001", Date.valueOf("2021-09-21"),  false), 
  ("tesco",     "001", Date.valueOf("2021-09-20"),  false),
  ("tesco",     "001", Date.valueOf("2021-01-30"),  false),
  ("tesco",     "001", Date.valueOf("2021-01-01"),  true)))
  .toDF("accountId", "customerId", "sessionDate", "didPurchase")
  
df.registerTempTable("myvisits")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the `MIN` window function with a CASE expression to identify the oldest purchase `sessionDate` and filter records that have occurred on or before that to achieve your desired results.

The sql to achieve this could look like

```sql
SELECT
    accountId,
    customerId,
    sessionDate,
    didPurchase
FROM (
    SELECT 
        *,
        MIN(CASE
            WHEN didPurchase THEN sessionDate
        END) OVER (
            PARTITION BY accountId, customerId
        ) as prior_oldest_purchase
     FROM
        myvisits
) v
WHERE
     v.sessionDate <= v.prior_oldest_purchase
ORDER BY
    accountId DESC, customerId,sessionDate DESC
```

[View live demo working db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwTAciYq72b8UYFP5LtEqJ/1)

Using the scala api, this could look like

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val customerAccountWindow = Window.partitionBy("accountId","customerId")

val outputDf = df.withColumn(
                    "prior_oldest_purchase",
                    min(
                        when(col("didPurchase"),col("sessionDate"))
                    ).over(customerAccountWindow)
               )
               .where(col("sessionDate") <= col("prior_oldest_purchase"))
               .select(
                   col("accountId"),
                   col("customerId"),
                   col("sessionDate"),
                   col("didPurchase")
               )
               .orderBy(
                   col("accountId").desc(),
                   col("customerId"),
                   col("sessionDate").desc()
               )
```

or using the pyspark api

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import Window

customerAccountWindow = Window.partitionBy("accountId","customerId")

outputDf = (
    df.withColumn(
        "prior_oldest_purchase",
        F.min(
            F.when(F.col("didPurchase"),F.col("sessionDate"))
        ).over(customerAccountWindow)
    )
    .where(F.col("sessionDate") <= F.col("prior_oldest_purchase"))
    .select(
        F.col("accountId"),
        F.col("customerId"),
        F.col("sessionDate"),
        F.col("didPurchase")
     )
     .orderBy(
        F.col("accountId").desc(),
        F.col("customerId"),
        F.col("sessionDate").desc()
      )
)
```

Let me know if this works for you.